# Delete spaces between section into grouped UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

It's possible to delete this little space between two sections of a grouped UITableView?

I reduced it by setting these two values:

[image]

And with this code inside:

```
- (UIView*) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.0;
}
```

But I still see the gray space.

This is my best result:

[image]

I want to delete the little grey line when I erase the grey space.

Comment: If you don't want them separated, why do you use grouped sections?

Comment: I need it... Trust me!! :D

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem a while ago.. solved returning `0.1` or probably `0.01` depending from what you prefer..

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 0.1/*0.01*/;
}
```

`return 0` or `nil` seems to reset the height.. this also work for the header..

This solved my problem, hope this solves yours..